# Passport already installed, but personal access client not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have configured Laravel API with Passport (Password Grant) for Nuxt a long time ago, I have no problem to log users, but now I need to create an access token manually for specific purpose.

However, when I try to create a token for a user as below, I'm getting an error:

```
$user = MyCompany\MyPackage\Models\User::find(123);
$user->createToken('my token')

   RuntimeException  Personal access client not found. Please create one.
```

What's missing in my configuration?

Below is my User model:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyPackage\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use Notifiable;

    ...

}
```

Comment: have you did the `php artisan passport:client --personal `?

Comment: @francisco No, I didn't... The Nuxt frontend works fine with the Laravel API and Passport already storing user tokens in `oauth_access_tokens` which I can revoke with `$request->user()->token()->revoke()`, what would this command change?

Comment: @francisco Actually, I already have client IDs, used by 3 different frontends. Using `php artisan passport:client --personal` just creates a new one.

Comment: In order to use `createTokens()`, you need to have `personal access` token on DB. You can have on you DB many client IDS, for (password, client grant). 
check you `.env`, and put the personal id/secret on   
  `PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=client-id-value`
    `PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=unhashed-client-secret-value`

Comment: @francisco That worked, thanks! But, what if I want to use different `client-id-value` ?

Comment: that I don't know. Why you want more personal tokens on the laravel app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `createTokens()`, you need to have `personal access` token on DB, and you can use the command `php artisan passport:client --personal`.

You can have on you DB many client IDS for password, client grant.

On your`.env` put the personal id/secret on:

```
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=client-id-value
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=unhashed-client-secret-value
```